# How to execute a package.json script from a node.js script file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

Let's imagine that we have such package.json scripts section:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "npm run lint:fix && tsc",
  },
}
```

We can execute this script via CMD by: `npm run compile`

How to do it via any Node.js script? 
Eg. I want to run the script file and these commands should execute.

I'm interested in any option: Run the package.json script from the node script or just run the commands separately in the script somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exec` from node.js and it will execute shell commands:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("npm run compile", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```